# How to play same audio clip multiple times using JavaFX MediaPlayer

Tags: java, javafx, audio, kotlin

I want to implement a simple task:
when a button is clicked, I want to play a sound.
I have 3 separate buttons that, when clicked, call the same function.
In this function, I play the audio clip.
The tricky part is: sometimes the buttons work just fine, sometimes not at all, which is super weird to me since they all call the same function.

I've browsed other javafx-audio-related questions but they are all about the audio not playing at all, whereas in my case it seems to play only sometimes?

FXML snippet:

```
<ImageView fx:id="bomb1" fitHeight="32.0" fitWidth="32.0" 
           onMouseClicked="#useTheBomb"
           pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
    <Image url="@bombs/bomb1.png"/>
    <cursor>
        <Cursor fx:constant="HAND"/>
    </cursor>
</ImageView>
<ImageView fx:id="bomb2" fitHeight="32.0" fitWidth="32.0" 
           onMouseClicked="#useTheBomb"
           pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
    <Image url="@bombs/bomb2.png"/>
    <cursor>
        <Cursor fx:constant="HAND"/>
    </cursor>
</ImageView>
<ImageView fx:id="bomb4" fitHeight="32.0" fitWidth="32.0" 
           onMouseClicked="#useTheBomb"
           pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
    <Image url="@bombs/bomb4.png"/>
    <cursor>
        <Cursor fx:constant="HAND"/>
    </cursor>
</ImageView>
```

This code is placed in my FXML Controller class

```
private val explosion = App::class.java.getResource("/bombs/explosion.mp3").toString()
private fun explode() = MediaPlayer(Media(explosion)).play()
```

the function that is called by the buttons:

```
fun useTheBomb() {
        explode()

        /* rest of the function does not concern audio at all, 
         * but I include it in case there's maybe some voodoo magic 
         * underneath that I don't know about
         * bombArray: Array<ImageView>
         */        
        with(bombArray[brikks.bombs++]) {
            image = exploded
            onMouseClicked = null
            cursor = Cursor.DEFAULT
        }
}
```

I get no errors when clicking the buttons

I also modyfied my program to allow the buttons to be clicked multiple times, and out of 30 tries the audio failed to play 6 times randomly. I couldn't see a pattern.

Comment: An [AudioClip](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.media/javafx/scene/media/AudioClip.html) is a better fit for this task than the MediaPlayer you are using.

Comment: You're right it's way easier to use and fits better since I only want to play a 2-second audio clip. Thanks for suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found a workaround

```
private val explosion = Media(App::class.java.getResource("/bombs/explosion.mp3").toString())
```

and then inside the `useTheBomb()` function:

```
MediaPlayer(explosion).play()
```

Tried it like a 100 times and worked everytime.
Don't know why tho.